Question about Proof of the Integrability of $f$ and $f_1,f_2,\dots,$ in Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem
I am self-studying measure theory and got stuck on part of the proof of the Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem:

Theorem$\quad$ 2.4.5$\quad$ (Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem) Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, let $g$ be a $[0,+\infty]$-valued integrable function on $X$, and let $f$ and $f_1,f_2,\dots$ be $[-\infty,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$ such that
\begin{align}
    f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\tag1
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
    |f_n(x)| \leq g(x),\ n=1,2,\dots\tag2
\end{align}
hold at $\mu$-almost every $x$ in $X$. Then $f$ and $f_1,f_2,\dots$ are integrable, and $\int fd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_nd\mu$.

When proving the theorem, the book claims that "the integrability of $f$ and $f_1,f_2,\dots$ follows from that of $g$; see Proposition 2.3.8, Proposition 2.3.9, and part (c) of Proposition 2.3.4." (I added these results at the bottom of this post.)
I could not see how the integrability of $f$ and $f_1,f_2,\dots$ follow immediately from that of $g$ by applying these results. The most important reason is that the relationship (1) and (2) does not hold at every $x$ in $X$, but instead, hold at $\mu$-almost every $x$ in $X$, which makes it illegal to directly apply Proposition 2.3.4 (c). So, I tried to prove it myself.
Here are my questions for this post:
1. Is my proof of the integrability of $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{f_1,f_2,\dots}$ correct? (For example, I have doubts about the relation $\left\{x\in X:\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x)| > g(x)\right\} \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\{x\in X:|f_n(x)|>g(x)\right\}$ I used in my proof.)
2. Am I overcomplicating anything here? (I am worried about this because the book's claim sounds like the proof shouldn't be that complicated.)
3. From my attempt below and the rest of proof of $\mathbf{\int fd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_nd\mu}$ presented in the book, it seems that we are not allow to conclude that $\mathbf{\int\lim_{n\to\infty}f_nd\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_nd\mu}$. But why?
Here is my attempt to prove the integrability of $f$ and $f_1,f_2,\dots$:

Proof of the integrability of $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{f_1,f_2,\dots}$$\quad$
We first prove the integrability of $\mathbf{f_1,f_2,\dots}$. Let $n$ be a positive integer. The fact that $|f_n(x)|\leq g(x)$ holds almost everywhere implies that there is an $N\in\mathscr{A}$ such that $\mu(N)=0$ and $\{x\in X:|f_n(x)|>g(x)\}\subseteq N$. Since $|f_n|$ and $g$ are $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions, the set $\{x\in X:|f_n(x)|>g(x)\} \in \mathscr{A}$ by Proposition 2.1.3. So, we can let $N = \{x\in X:|f_n(x)|>g(x)\}$ and conclude that $\mu(\{x\in X:|f_n(x)|>g(x)\})=0$. Since $g$ is integrable and $[0,+\infty]$-valued, it follows that $\int g^+d\mu = \int gd\mu < +\infty$. Assume to the contrary that $\int|f_n|d\mu = \sup\left\{\int hd\mu:h \in \mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ h\leq|f_n|\right\} = +\infty$. Then, as $\int gd\mu<+\infty$, there exists an $h\in\mathscr{S}_+$ such that $h\leq|f_n|$ and $\int hd\mu > \int gd\mu$. Denote this $h$ by $h=\sum_{i=1}^ma_i\chi_{A_i}$, where $a_1,\dots,a_m$ are nonnegative real numbers and $A_1,\dots,A_m$ are disjoint subsets of $X$ that belong to $\mathscr{A}$. Then
\begin{align}
\int|f_n|d\mu \geq \int hd\mu = \sum_{i=1}^ma_i\mu(A_i) > \int gd\mu = \sup\left\{\int pd\mu:p\in\mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ p\leq g\right\}.
\end{align}
The set $\{x\in X:h(x)>g(x)\}\neq\emptyset$, for otherwise $h(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x$ in $X$ would imply $\int hd\mu \leq \int gd\mu$ (see Proposition 2.3.4 (c)). Without loss of generality, suppose $\{x\in X:h(x) > g(x)\} = \bigcup_{i=1}^kA_i$ and $\{x\in X:h(x) \leq g(x)\} = \bigcup_{i=k+1}^mA_i$. So for any $x\in A_i$, $i=k+1,\dots,m$, we have $a_i\leq g(x)$. Define a function $p\in\mathscr{S}_+$ be such that $p(x) = a_i$ for all $x\in A_i$ where $i=k+1,\dots,m$, and $p(x)=0$ for all $x\in A_i$ where $i=1,\dots,k$. Then $p\leq g$ and $\int pd\mu = \sum_{i=1}^ma_i\mu(A_i)$. Now, if $\mu(\{x\in X:h(x)>g(x)\}) = \mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^kA_i) = \bigcup_{i=1}^k\mu(A_i) = 0$, then $\mu(A_i)=0$ for $i=1,\dots,k$, so that $\int hd\mu = \sum_{i=1}^ma_i\mu(A_i) = \int pd\mu \leq \int gd\mu$, contradicting the fact that $\int hd\mu > \int gd\mu$. Thus, $\mu(\{x\in X:h(x)>g(x)\}) > 0$. But $\{x\in X:h(x)>g(x)\}\subseteq\{x\in X:|f_n(x)|>g(x)\}$. So we get $\mu(\{x\in X:|f_n(x)|>g(x)\})>\mu(\{x\in X:h(x)>g(x)\})>0$, contradicting the fact that $\mu(\{x\in X:|f_n(x)|>g(x)\})=0$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
\int|f_n|d\mu = \sup\left\{\int hd\mu:h\in\mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ h\leq|f_n|\right\} < +\infty.
\end{align}
Hence, $|f_n|$ is integrable. By Proposition 2.3.8, $f_n$ is integrable.
Next, we prove the integrability of $\mathbf{f}$. By Proposition 2.1.5, $\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n|$ and $g$ are $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions, it follows that $\{x\in X:\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x)|>g(x)\}\in\mathscr{A}$. Since $\{x\in X:\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x)|>g(x)\}\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x\in X:|f_n(x)|>g(x)\}$ and $\mu(\{x\in X:|f_n(x)|>g(x)\})=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it follows that $\mu(\{x\in X:\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n(x)|>g(x)\})=0$. Thus, $\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n|\leq g$ holds $\mu$-almost everywhere. Then, by a similar argument, we can conclude that
\begin{align}
\int\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n|d\mu = \sup\left\{\int d\mu:h\in\mathscr{S}_+\ \text{and}\ h \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n|\right\}<+\infty.
\end{align}
Hence, $\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n| = |\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n|$ is integrable. By Proposition 2.3.8, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$ is integrable. Since $f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ holds at $\mu$-almost every $x$ in $X$, by Proposition 2.3.9, $\int fd\mu$ exists and $\int fd\mu = \int\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)d\mu$ which is finite given the integrability of $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$. This implies $f$ is integrable.

Thank you very much for any help!

Results used in my attempt:

Proposition 2.1.3$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A})$ be a measurable space, let $A$ be a subset of $X$ that belongs to $\mathscr{A}$, and let $f$ and $g$ be $[-\infty,+\infty]$-valued measurable functions on $A$. Then the sets $\{x \in A:f(x) < g(x)\}$, $\{x \in A:f(x) \leq g(x)\}$, and $\{x \in A:f(x) = g(x)\}$ belong to $\mathscr{A}$.


Proposition 2.1.5$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A})$ be a measurable space, let $A$ be a subset of $X$ that belongs to $\mathscr{A}$, and let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of $[-\infty,+\infty]$-valued measurable functions on $A$. Then
(a) the functions $\sup_nf_n$ and $\inf_nf_n$ are measurable,
(b) the functions $\limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty}f_n$ are measurable, and
(c) the function $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n$ (whose domain is $\{x\in A:\limsup_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\liminf_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\}$) is measurable.


Proposition 2.3.4$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, let $f$ and $g$ be $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$m and let $\alpha$ be a nonnegative real number. Then
(a) $\int \alpha fd\mu = \alpha\int fd\mu$,
(b) $\int(f+g)d\mu = \int fd\mu+\int gd\mu$, and
(c) if $f(x)\leq g(x)$ holds at each $x$ in $X$, then $\int fd\mu \leq \int gd\mu$.


Proposition 2.3.8$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f$ be a $[-\infty,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable function on $X$. Then $f$ is integrable if and only if $|f|$ is integrable. If these functions are integrable, then $|\int fd\mu|\leq\int|f|d\mu$.


Proposition 2.3.9$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f$ and $g$ be $[-\infty,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$ that agree almost everywhere. If either $\int fd\mu$ or $\int gd\mu$ exists, then both exist, and $\int fd\mu = \int gd\mu$.


Reference$\quad$ Measure Theory by Donald Cohn.

With all due respect, but I have not read your entire answer. But in $L^1$, you can always argue under the integral and use its monotonicity: $\int \lvert f \rvert =  \int \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lvert f_n \rvert \leq \int \lvert g \rvert < \infty$. I used Fatou's lemma. This gives you integrability for $f$. An anlaogous argument gives it for the $f_n$. See also this for how to treat $L^p$.

Ad your 3. question. Consider $f_n(x) = \exp(-(x-n))^2$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. You can see that the inequality does not hold. Use substitution $x-n=y$ to compute $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n$.

Couldn't help but edit "demonated" in the title to "dominated". An interesting description, though. :)

@paulgarrett Hahahahah! My bad! Thanks for correcting that!

"The most important reason is that the relationship (1) and (2) does not hold at every $x$ in $X$, but instead, hold at $\mu$-almost every $x$ in $X$, which makes it illegal to directly apply Proposition 2.3.4 (c)." Indeed, so let $A$ be the set of all $x$ so that $(1)$ doesn't hold. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for each $x \in A$, re-define $f_n(x)$ so that it's zero and re-define $f(x)$ so that it's zero. Oh, would you look at that? Now, condition $(1)$ is satisfied for all $x$. Try to adapt this small bit of reasoning so you can apply previously known results.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend Thanks for your comment about my question 3. As for your first comment, I couldn't see how's that relation based on Fatou's Lemma. The version of Fatou's Lemma I learned is this: Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$. Then $\int\liminf_{n\to\infty}f_nd\mu \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\int f_nd\mu.$

Sry. I deleted the Fatou part. So I did not actually use it xD

@Mousedorff Thanks a lot for your help! I was wondering wouldn't that "redefining" step be "with loss of generality"?

Why would you lose generality? It's a standard property of the Lebesgue integral that it does not "see" sets of measure zero. So, you can change the function however you want on a set of measure zero and it isn't going to affect the value of the integral (which is what you're concerned with).

@Mousedorff Please bear with me. But this isn't necessarily Lebesgue integral. The $\mathscr{A}$ could be any $\sigma$-algebra and the measure $\mu$ may not be Lebesgue. So in this case, are we still allowed to do the redefining?

Yes, this is generally true. You can approximate any measurable function by simple functions (see e.g. Evans, Gariepy - Measure Theory and fine properties of functions, Thm. 1.12), so you only have to show $\int_{A\setminus N } g = \int_A g$ for an arbitrary simple function (these are functions with finite image) $g$ and a set $N$ of measure $0$. Maybe you can prove this by applying the definition of the integral. Let me know if you have problems. Sorry @Mousedorff for maybe taking your answer away...

@Beerus Aha there’s a terminology difference, I suppose. So, when I say “Lebesgue Integral”, I am referring to the general measure-theoretic construction of the integral. It’s okay to do the re-defining even in that case because the property I cited (the integral vanishing on sets of measure zero) still holds.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend Thanks a lot!

@Mousedorff Thanks a lot!

Use additivity of the integral and the fact that $h = 0$ a.e. implies $\int h = 0$ to obtain
\begin{align}
\int |f_n|\,d\mu &= \int |f_n|(1_{|f_n| \leq g} + 1_{|f_n| > g})\,d\mu \\
&= \int |f_n|1_{|f_n| \leq g}\,d\mu + \int |f_n|1_{|f_n| > g}\,d\mu \\
&= \int |f_n|1_{|f_n| \leq g}\,d\mu \\
&\leq \int g1_{|f_n| \leq g}\,d\mu \\
&= \int g\,d\mu
\end{align}
